# Wait on any future in Java 8 without creating thread per future

Tags: java, java-8, future

I have a collection of futures and I would like to wait on any of them, meaning have a blocking call that will return once any future is done.

I saw `CompletableFuture.anyOf()` but if I understood its code correctly it creates a thread per future, I would like to use a less wasteful approach in terms of resources, if its possible in Java.

Comment: If you need to fine-tune the thread-behavior, create a [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and throw your futures at it instead. For example using `invokeAny​`. Create instances of the service using [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html), there you can also define your thread-restrictions.

Comment: *"less wasteful approach in terms of resources"* - note that the *default behavior* is usually very good. Do not try to be smarter than what the experts created, the outcome is often much slower. Only optimize if you identified an issue and can measure the difference of both implementations.

Comment: *"if I understood its code correctly it creates a thread per future"* - where did you see that? The documentation does not specify the threading-behavior at all. And in the [current implementation](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.java#L2427) I do not really see anything like that, at least not obvious. It probably uses the default executor service like the other methods in that class, which grows and shrinks its thread pool dynamically depending on demand. Try to follow the `tryFire` method.

Comment: Thats a dufferent impl than what I have, I forgot to mention (edited) but im using Java 8 which seems to use a `ForkJoinPool`.

Comment: Not sure I understood your suggestion regarding the executor service, are suggesting I created a runnable for each future that does `get`?

Comment: Im "optimizing" because I know that an approach of creating a thread per future wont work for me...

Comment: If you use the methods in `CompletableFuture`, they are using a default `ExecutorService`, as you just mentioned (the fork join pool). If you do not like that, you can always create your own service and throw your tasks at it directly. As explained. For example `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)` and then `service.invokeAny(...)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208358/discussion-between-thedarklord-and-zabuza).

Comment: Use a [`CompletionService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html). Or do what it does. Add a `runAfter` (possibly `async` - you'll need to read up on the caveats of using one or the other) that pushes the results into a `BlockingQueue`.

Comment: It doesn’t matter which version you are looking at, `anyOf` does not create new threads.

Comment: @Holger Can you point me to the relevant piece of code that shows that? Im very interested to learn the mechanism they use in order to achieve that

Comment: Which is “the relevant piece of code” in which something doesn’t happen? It’s just not how `CompletableFuture` works. Unless you use one of the `…Async` methods, no thread will be created. And the `…Async` methods only create a thread when the executor they are delegating to does.

Comment: The piece of code where the waiting for the futures actually happens, where I'll be able to see how its done (and consequently, if you are indeed right, see its done without creating threads)

Comment: Since `anyOf` does not wait, there is no waiting code to show. `anyOf` returns a new `CompletableFuture` and only if you call `get` or `join` on it it will be your thread that will get blocked. Whichever thread completes one of the specified futures will unblock your thread.

Answer (score 1):

Straight answer is yes, here's a sample method

```java
    private <T> CompletableFuture<T> waitAny(List<CompletableFuture<T>> allFutures) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
        while (!thread.isInterrupted()) {
            for (CompletableFuture<T> future : allFutures) {
                if (future.isDone()) {
                    return future;
                }
            }
            Thread.sleep(50L);
        }
        throw new InterruptedException();
    }
```

Second option

```java
    private <T> CompletableFuture<T> waitAny(List<CompletableFuture<T>> allFutures) throws InterruptedException {
        CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<T>> any = new CompletableFuture<>();
        for (CompletableFuture<T> future : allFutures) {
            future.handleAsync((t, throwable) -> {
                any.complete(future);
                return null;
            });
        }
        try {
            return any.get();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
```

but the whole context of the task is unclear,
there's probably more optimal solution.